# Shift months/years in Python by integer input

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to shift the month and years in a given column based on an integer value. `a2` column is effected when we input the `integer: 9`
We are incrementing the month by the value 9. We start with month 4 and add 9 more months = `1/1/2023`

**Data**

```
start       a1          a2          stat        exit
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    4/1/2022    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    4/1/2022    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    4/1/2022    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
```

**Desired output**

```
start       a1          a2          stat        exit
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    1/1/2023    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    1/1/2023    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
1/1/2018    1/1/2022    1/1/2023    5/1/2022    6/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
   d = {
             'm1': pd.DateOffset(months=3),
             'de': pd.DateOffset(months=5),
             're': pd.DateOffset(months=2),
             }
         s = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue)

monthvalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter month value: "))   #enter 9

new = pd.Series(d).rsub(datevalue) \
                     .append(pd.Series({'a2': monthvalue}))
```

I am still researching this. Any suggestions is helpful. I am not sure if we can `mix` `datetime` w./ integer input.

Comment: Try `df["a2"] += pd.DateOffset(months=int(input()))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`pd.DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html):

```
# Convert all columns to pandas datetime
In [558]: df = pd.DataFrame([pd.to_datetime(df[i]) for i in df.columns]).T

# Take user input for monthvalue
In [559]: monthvalue = int(input("Enter month value: "))
Enter month value: 9

# If monthvalue entered by user is 9, then add 9 months to column 'a2'
In [560]: if monthvalue == 9:
     ...:     df['a2'] = df['a2']  + pd.DateOffset(months=monthvalue)
     ...: 

In [561]: df
Out[561]: 
       start         a1         a2       stat       exit
0 2018-01-01 2022-01-01 2023-01-01 2022-05-01 2022-06-01
1 2018-01-01 2022-01-01 2023-01-01 2022-05-01 2022-06-01
2 2018-01-01 2022-01-01 2023-01-01 2022-05-01 2022-06-01
```

Comment: To accommodate any integer that the user may input, would I have to add into the loops with else == 1, elif == 2… and so forth? @mayank

Comment: Do you want to change `a2` column values only if a particular integer is entered by user? or for anything?

Comment: Hi @mayank, I wish to have the other columns shift based on a dictionary. (I updated) But the user should be able to input any integer btw 1 - 12 (month)

Comment: Please also edit your question to include the expected output based on the dictionary you added.

Comment: Sure I will do this